# Proving the equivalence of a complex polynomial and a strange series.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a homework question:

Let $f(z) = 1 + z + 2z^2 + 3z^3 + 5z^4 + 8z^5 + 13z^6 + ...$.

(a): Show that $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$ for all z in the disk  $\{z: |z| < R\}$ for some number R.

(b): Find the value of R in part (a).

My professor gave us a hint: show that $f$ satisfies the equation $f(z) = 1 + zf(z)+ z^2f(z)$.

I know that the series is something like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n$ where $c_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number, but I don't know how to approach showing equivalence.

I don't think that I understand how his hint helps us. I feel like it should be my jumping off point for this problem, but I don't see how it helps me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(z)=1+zf(z)+z^{2}f(z)$ gives you (by comparing coefficient of $z^{n}$ on both sides) $c_{n+2}=c_{n+1}+c_n$. Since $c_0=f(0)$ and $c_1=f'(0)$ you can easily write down $c_n$ for every $n$.